# How do I add The Simpson's characters to Lego Dimensions?

Tags: lego-dimensions

I tried to register Bart and Krusty, with my brother. However, we can only get them to register as blank toys.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Help me be able to play

Answer (score 1):

When building new Lego Dimension toys, it's important to use the correct base.  Bart's base has a picture of his slingshot on it, and Krusty's has his bow tie.

If Bart and Krusty are both showing up as blank toys, chances are you mixed their bases up with the bases for their vehicles.  If you put them on the correct bases, they should be recognized by the game.  Then you can build the vehicles and register them to their bases.

If you don't have Bart or Krusty's base, you may have ended up with a defective fun pack, and you should talk to whoever you bought it from.